# How do I automatically start a .NET Core 3.1 API when the docker container starts?

Tags: docker, .net-core

When I deploy my .NET Core WebAPI to a Docker container, it fails to "run" by default. (It's dotnet that doesn't run, the actual container runs as expected)

Running `docker ps -a` shows the container with a Status of "UP":

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS          PORTS                   NAMES
eb3fa8be5101  firstapi:dev  "tail -f /dev/null" 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes    0.0.0.0:32790->80/tcp   MyFirstApi
```

Attempting to hit "http://localhost:32790/api/WeatherForecast" shows an error in the browser (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) and "Error: socket hang up" in Postman.

When I debug this project in Visual Studio (the debugging project is set to "Docker Compose") I can successfully hit the API.

[image: debug as docker compose]

As soon as I stop debugging, I can't reach the endpoints again.

When I shell into the container and manually launch the API, it works from my browser again:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker exec -it eb3 /bin/bash
root@eb3fa8be5101:/app# cd /app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/
root@eb3fa8be5101:/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1# dotnet FirstApi.dll

[18:43:16 INF] Starting up
[18:43:16 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:80
[18:43:16 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[18:43:16 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[18:43:16 INF] Content root path: /app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1
```

My dockerfile looks pretty standard, untouched from when VS generated it:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["/FirstApi.csproj", "FirstApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FirstApi/FirstApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FirstApi"
RUN dotnet build "FirstApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FirstApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FirstApi.dll"]
```

And my launchSettings.json file is also pretty standard:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": false
    }
  }
}
```

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  firstapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}firstapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FirstApi/Dockerfile
```

And the docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  firstapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

Comment: So, debugging works just fine when you start it from VS using the Docker config, correct? Your issue is that when you stop debugging, you can no longer reach your app? If so, this sounds like normal behavior. When you stop debugging, it stops the container. I am understanding correctly?

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I'm fairly new to docker in general. I realized that, when apps are to be published into production, it should be as simple as running:
```docker-compose up --build``` to get the container started. This works locally too.

Answer (score 1):

Running `docker-compose up --build` from outside Visual Studio will rebuild and run the container as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that port 80 is causing the issue. Port 80 is taken by IIS and could cause issues when you run a container. Map it to some other port.

```
firstapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - **"8000:80"**
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

Comment: I don't want my application to always run on 8000 though. It should bind to any port on the host as it will need to scale as the load increases.

Comment: That should not be a problem in your cloud environment where you won't have IIS running. If you want to run this as docker container locally, either stop IIS and run this on 80 or map to different port (like 8000).